# Edit tag wiki (and excerpt) tag on the edit screen missing the tag itself

Tags: feature-request, bug, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

So here I was minding my site's business, approving a few tag wiki excerpts and tag wikis, editing some of them along the way. Lo and behold, I opened one to edit it, but I forgot what the exact tag was. Couldn't find it anywhere on the screen.

### Can we maybe *add* that information to the edit page?

So I go to improve this link here ...

[image: So I go to improve this link here ...]

And forgot what tag wiki excerpt I was editing in the first place ...

[image: This is what it SHOULD look like I think]